# Dynamics CRM Workflow Update Field with Month of Current Date

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Trying to find a way using a Dynamics CRM 2013 Online Workflow to update a record and store the current month (or better yet the month number) in a field.  Is this possible?

For example, I'd like the workflow to update a record and change a "month" field to "January" or even better the number 1 (as a number).

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Custom Workflow Activity like this one:

http://wfdatetimeutilities.codeplex.com/

or you can create a new one by yourself, more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, this solution won't import.  Perhaps it's for an earlier version of CRM.  I'm using CRM Online 2013.

Comment: the download is provided as .dll, you need to register it using the plugin registration tool included inside the SDK. The source code is a Visual Studio solution, not a CRM Solution. The library works with CRM 2013

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I don't see a .dll for this.  There are .dll's in the /Libraries folder, but I'm assuming those are for something else.  I see the .sln Visual Studio Solution file, but I don't have Visual Studio so I can't create a .dll from that. Suggestions?

Comment: open the link, go to downloads tab, under "Other Available Downloads" the first link (is written "application"). After use this tutorial to register it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515.aspx